# Java-Read values from excel to a object

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read a very large excel file Apache POI. I have managed to read the file but i am able to store the values to a object. I am doing so because i have to change some values and then add it to a table.
Below is the code

```
protected void processSheet(StylesTable styles,
        ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings, InputStream sheetInputStream) 
        throws IOException, SAXException {
    InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
    SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader sheetParser = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        System.out.println("sheet is not read");
        ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(styles, strings, new SheetContentsHandler() {

        @Override
            public void startRow(int rowNum) {


                System.out.println("rwnum"+rowNum);

            }
            @Override
            public void endRow() {
                System.out.println("endrow");
            }
            @Override
            public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue) {

            }
            @Override
            public void headerFooter(String text, boolean isHeader, String tagName) {

            }

        }, 
        false//means result instead of formula
        );


        sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);

        sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SAX parser appears to be broken - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "very large" mean (number of rows and columns, and what is the file size)?

Comment: What kind of object do you have in mind?

Comment: @Axel Very Large means..number of rows to 21k and columns to be 90. Size of the file is around 8MB

Comment: @IIogiq Object is java entity beans. My idea is to read the values from the excel file and save those in a object. Add the object to Arraylist and save the list to the database using jpa.

Comment: @user3894012 that's rather a normal size IMHO (I regulary have to deal with > 500k rows). Now, what do you want to do when you have read the file? Do you just want to extract information, or do you want to add new rows and columns or change existing data?